# how to send hexadecimal data packets using Bluetooth in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy

It's my first time using Dart and Flutter.
I want to send and receive data packets to some device.
I tried a lot of things through google but failed.
Please let me know how I can send it.
Please help me.

```dart
void sendData() async {
Uint8List list = new Uint8List(13);
list[0]=0x80;
list[1]=0x80;
list[2]=0xF0;
list[3]=0x7D;
list[4]=0x05;
list[5]=0x00;
list[6]=0x0E;
list[7]=0x01;
list[8]=0x70;
list[9]=0x70;
list[10]=127;
list[11]=0x80;
list[12]=0xF7;
print(list);
  
await _curPeripheral.discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics();

_curPeripheral.writeCharacteristic(
    "Service Uuid",
    "Charactoristic Uuid",
    Uint8List.fromList(list), false);
```

---- debug Console ----

```
D/com.polidea.flutter_ble_lib.FlutterBleLibPlugin(22538): on native side observed method: discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics
D/com.polidea.flutter_ble_lib.FlutterBleLibPlugin(22538): on native side observed method: writeCharacteristicForDevice
```

Comment: You have to provide a service and characteristic uuid. Have a look at the examples here: https://github.com/dotintent/FlutterBleLib#manipulating-characteristics

Comment: I already know my uuid, even if uuid is used, the on native side obseved method is printed. Instead of my uuid, I edited it with "Service Uuid" and "Charactoristic Uuid," sorry to confuse you.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple different libraries to choose if you want to send and receive data using Bluetooth Low Energy. For flutter you could use [flutter_reactive_ble](https://github.com/PhilipsHue/flutter_reactive_ble) for example. The description includes usage examples.

Another library for flutter is [flutter_blue](https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue).

Comment: Thanks but the libraries are not available because of null safety.
Migrate is not running.
Can you tell me the problem by looking at the part I coded using flutter_ble_lib?

Comment: @BigHead Where is the part you coded? Please edit your question and add it there

Comment: I didn't know because it was my first time using it. I'm
I just posted it. Thank you.